# Changes to variable set in subscription are getting mirrored by another variable

Tags: javascript, angular

On `(change)` that occurs on a `select` element, I am invoking a function that subscribes to an observable from a service:

```
this.barcode.getGroup(this.groupName).subscribe(data => {
  this.docs = data['value']; // 36 objects in array
  this.barcodeItems = data['value']; // 36 objects in array
    this.addAnyBarcodes();
  }
});
```

I am setting the global variables `docs` and `barcodeItems` to the value that is returned and then invoking another function named `addAnyBarcodes()`.

In this function, I am simply pushing a new object to `barcodeItems`, however, `docs` is also being updated.

```
addAnyBarcodes() {
  this.barcodeItems.push({name: "hello"})
  console.log(this.barcodeItems) // should be 37 objects
  console.log(this.docs) // should be 36 objects
}
```

Why is this happening? How can I only update `barcodeItems`?

Answer (score 0):

this is because arrays are reference values in javascript, so mutating it in one place will mutate it in all places as all variables it is assigned to hold a reference to the same array. to avoid this, treat arrays as immutable and avoid methods like `push` which mutates an array... do this instead:

```
this.barcodeItems = this.barcodeItems.concat([{name: "hello"}]);
```

or do this if you prefer:

```
this.barcodeItems = [...this.barcodeItems, {name: "hello"}];
```

concat is a safe method that creates a new array by combining 2 arrays instead of mutating an existing one, in the second case, you're actually declaring a new array and filling it with your previous array and your new item... in either case you won't have the reference issues.

Answer (score 0):

Both `docs` and `barcodeItems` point to the exact same object.
What you could do is create two different copies of `data['value']` and assign them :

```
this.barcode.getGroup(this.groupName).subscribe(data => {
  this.docs = data.value.slice(); //slice makes a shallow copy of the array
  this.barcodeItems = data.value.slice(); 
  this.addAnyBarcodes();
});
```

Alternatively, with ES6 you can clone an array this way :

```
this.docs = [... data.value];
```